# vmrun tool usage

Tags: vmware, vmware-server, vmware-tools

I have a vb script (that sets up the IIS). I need to run this vbscript inside the guest VM, from the Host box.

How do i do this? I am tol vmrun.exe can do this.

Any samples to get this done would be great help.

I am running VMWare server 2 in host.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the samples of running scripts in the Linux guest OS: http://communities.vmware.com/thread/171410

Other samples: http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/Controlling_VMware_Virtual_Machines_from_the_Command_Line_with_vmrun

http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/How_to_Remotely_Run,_List_and_Kill_Programs_Running_in_a_VMware_Virtual_Machine